# RegEx get last value from line under match

Tags: regex, vb.net

I need to find a way to get the last value from the line unter the matching value:

RegEx I have tried:

```
\b22001.*\s(\d.*[\d,]*)
```

Text example:

```
   22001      kerbs A4, 12/15/25cm, G341, R0.50, in plywood packages
              red mark - Jujia              9,36 m           Yuan    119,12 Yuan   1.114,96  68010000
   22014      kerbs A4, 12/15/25cm, G341, R12.00, in plywood packages
              red mark - Jujia             12,14 m           Yuan    119,12 Yuan   1.446,12  68010000
              order No. 1800883
  1001559     middlepieces to kerbs A4/A5, 20cm high, R6.00,
              frontedge rounded R=2 cm, in plywood packages
              red mark - Jujia             50,27 m           Yuan     99,12 Yuan   4.982,76  68010000
```

in this example I need the "1.114,96" and the "68010000"

Comment: Try `\b22001.*\n.* (\d[\d.,]*) +(\d[\d,]*)`

Comment: Thank you very much :) If you right this as answer I will mark it

Comment: Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(\b(\d[\d,.]+)\s+(\d[\d.,]+)$)
```

Demo: [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/w5VqJA/2)

Then you will get 2 capture groups.

`[0]` will give you  1.114,96

`[1]` will give you  68010000

> What happens here?
>
> `\b` boundary of the capture group `()`
>
> `\d` matches a number `[\d,.]` escapes `.` and `,`
>
> `$` matches the end of string
>
> You need to enable the multiline flag in order for this to work.

**UPDATE**

If you want to search for a specific entry **substitute `22014`**:

```
^\n?\r?\s*22014?.*\w*\s+\w.* (\d[\d,.]+)\s+(\d[\d,.]+)$
```

Demo: [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/w5VqJA/4)

Comment: Well, check the demos, it is working. Do you have trailing spaces at the end of the regex?

Comment: What are you trying to match with `\b(^[22001])*`, that means: word boundary, capture group: beginning of line, 1 digit in range 0,1,2 end group appears 0 or more times. That's crazy!

Comment: @Zam89 Good, I updated with a new version that can be used to filter a specific value too.

Comment: @Toto yeah, wasn't meant to post that haha, was scribbling and copied the concept from the wrong RegExr tab. Updated now.

Comment: That's because that entry is 3 lines long. I'll see what I can do for that one.

Answer (score 1):

You may match these value using

```
(?m)\b1001559\b.*(?:\n(?![\p{Zs}\t]*\d+[\p{Zs}\t])[\p{Zs}\t]{3,}.*?(?: (\d[\d.,]*) +(\d[\d,]*))?\r?$)+
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb22001%5cb.*%28%3f%3a%5cn%28%3f!%5b%5cp%7bZs%7d%5ct%5d*%5cd%2b%5b%5cp%7bZs%7d%5ct%5d%29%5b%5cp%7bZs%7d%5ct%5d%7b3%2c%7d.*%3f%28%3f%3a+%28%5cd%5b%5cd.%2c%5d*%29+%2b%28%5cd%5b%5cd%2c%5d*%29%29%3f%5cr%3f%24%29%2b&i=+++22001++++++kerbs+A4%2c+12%2f15%2f25cm%2c+G341%2c+R0.50%2c+in+plywood+packages%0d%0a++++++++++++++red+mark+-+Jujia++++++++++++++9%2c36+m+++++++++++Yuan++++119%2c12+Yuan+++1.114%2c96++68010000%0d%0a+++22014++++++kerbs+A4%2c+12%2f15%2f25cm%2c+G341%2c+R12.00%2c+in+plywood+packages%0d%0a++++++++++++++red+mark+-+Jujia+++++++++++++12%2c14+m+++++++++++Yuan++++119%2c12+Yuan+++1.446%2c12++68010000%0d%0a++++++++++++++order+No.+1800883%0d%0a++1001559+++++middlepieces+to+kerbs+A4%2fA5%2c+20cm+high%2c+R6.00%2c%0d%0a++++++++++++++frontedge+rounded+R%3d2+cm%2c+in+plywood+packages%0d%0a++++++++++++++red+mark+-+Jujia+++++++++++++50%2c27+m+++++++++++Yuan+++++99%2c12+Yuan+++4.982%2c76++68010000&o=im):

[image]

**Details**

- `(?m)` - Multiline mode on
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `1001559`  - a number
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `.*` - the rest of the line
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group #1:

  - `\n(?![\p{Zs}\t]*\d+[\p{Zs}\t])` - a newline not followed with 0+ horizontal whitespaces, 1+ digits and a horizontal whitespace
  - `[\p{Zs}\t]{3,}` - three or more horizontal whitespaces
  - `.*?`  - 0 or more chars other than a newline, as few as possible
  - `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group #2:

    - - a space
    - `(\d[\d.,]*)` - Group 1: a digit followed with 0 or more digits, `.` or `,` chars
    - `+` - 1+ spaces
    - `(\d[\d,]*)` - Group 2: a digit followed with 0 or more digits, `.` or `,` chars
  - `)?` - end of the group #2, match 1 or 0 times
  - `\r?$` - an optional CR and end of line anchor
- `)+` - end of non-capturing group #1.

See [VB.NET demo online](https://ideone.com/Fko3XM):

```
Imports System
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Class Test
    Public Shared Sub Main() 
        Dim strArtikel As String = "1001559"
        Dim pattern As String = "(?m)\b" & strArtikel & "\b.*(?:\n(?![\p{Zs}\t]*\d+[\p{Zs}\t])[\p{Zs}\t]{3,}.*?(?: (\d[\d.,]*) +(\d[\d,]*))?\r?$)+"
        Dim s As String = "   22001      kerbs A4, 12/15/25cm, G341, R0.50, in plywood packages" & vbCrLf & "              red mark - Jujia              9,36 m           Yuan    119,12 Yuan   1.114,96  68010000" & vbCrLf & "   22014      kerbs A4, 12/15/25cm, G341, R12.00, in plywood packages" & vbCrLf & "              red mark - Jujia             12,14 m           Yuan    119,12 Yuan   1.446,12  68010000" & vbCrLf & "              order No. 1800883" & vbCrLf & "  1001559     middlepieces to kerbs A4/A5, 20cm high, R6.00," & vbCrLf & "              frontedge rounded R=2 cm, in plywood packages" & vbCrLf & "              red mark - Jujia             50,27 m           Yuan     99,12 Yuan   4.982,76  68010000"
        Dim matches As MatchCollection = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(s, pattern)
        For Each m As Match In matches
            Console.WriteLine("Matches for '" & strArtikel & "'....")
            Console.WriteLine(m.Groups(1).Value)
            Console.WriteLine(m.Groups(2).Value)
        Next

    End Sub
End Class
```

Output:

```
Matches for '1001559'....
4.982,76
68010000
```

Comment: hmm if the number is 1001559 then I got 0 matches

Comment: `\b22001` is hardcoded here, why not escape a digit instead?

Comment: I see the issue, something it could happen, that the values are not in the next line, they are 2 lines after this "search" value

Comment: Wiktor, you are still hardcoding a value that OP is not interested in obtaining before parsing the data. (i.e. 1001559) This means your regex will only work for that specific instance.

Comment: Hardcoding is ok: I need only the line for that number, in my loop I change the hardcodes number is this regex

Comment: Thanks, for some reason now it wont workd for 22001

Comment: @Zam89 it is because 1001559 is hardcoded.. you need to change it for each entry.

Comment: @Joel yes I do that ;) But the regex is mark everything till the end of the next block (22014) and Group1 & 2 are the values from 22014

Comment: @Zam89 I added a `(?![\p{Zs}\t]*\d+[\p{Zs}\t])` negative lookahead check to make sure the regex doesn't match across a line that starts with a number inside whitespaces.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks, that seams to work, now I have problem to get this into vb.net any Idea? ```r3.Pattern = "(?m)\b" & strArtikel & "\b.*(?:\n(?![\p{Zs}\t]*\d+[\p{Zs}\t])[\p{Zs}\t]{3,}.*?(?: (\d[\d.,]*) +(\d[\d,]*))?\r?$)+"``` Got en error if I execute this pattern

Comment: @Zam89 It looks to be working well, see [VB.NET demo](https://ideone.com/Fko3XM)

Comment: my mistake, sorry  I mean vba